# how can I remove a room in arraylist Room by name?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm learning java. I have trouble about arraylist in my java program. How can I remove a room in arraylist in Room and count the number of rooms has the size smaller than 40. I just coded 2 methods which were removeRoom and countRoomBySize in class MyRoom. My code has error in Net Beans.  Anyone help me to check this code, please. Thank so much. Here is my code
 My Main class

```
public class MyMain { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create a list of rooms
    MyRoom m = new MyRoom();

    m.addRoom(new Room("HB201L",35));
    m.addRoom(new Room("HB401R",45));
    m.addRoom(new Room("211",30));

    m.sort();
    m.list();

    //1.
    m.removeRoom("211");
    m.list();


    //2.
    int c = m.countRoomBySize(40);
    System.out.println(c);//2
}   
}
```

Class Room

```
public class Room implements Comparable<Room> {
@Override
public int compareTo(Room o) {
    return o.name.compareToIgnoreCase(this.name);
}
//instanced variables
private int size;  
private String name;

public Room() {
    name = "";
    size = 0;
}

public Room(String name, int size) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}   
}
```

Class MyRoom

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyRoom implements IRoom {

List<Room> rooms;

public MyRoom() {
    rooms = new ArrayList();
}

@Override
public void addRoom(Room r) {
    //append r to the end of list rooms
    rooms.add(r);
}

@Override
public void list() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.size(); i++) {
        Room r = rooms.get(i);
        System.out.printf("%-20s%-10d\n",r.getName(),r.getSize());
    }
}

@Override
public void removeRoom(){
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.size(); i++) {
        if(rooms.get(i).getName() == "211")
            rooms.remove(rooms);
    }
}

@Override
public int countRoomBySize(){
     int s,i,n;
 n = rooms.size();
 s = 0;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
   if(rooms.get(i).getSize() > 40) 
       s++;  
 }
 return(s); 
}

public void sort() {
    Collections.sort(rooms);
}   
}

Interface IRoom
public interface IRoom {
//only contain public members: constants and method declaration
public final int MAX = 10;
public void addRoom(Room r);
public void list();
public void removeRoom();
public int countRoomBySize();
}
interface A {
void f();
} 
interface B extends A {
void g();
}
interface C {}
```

Comment: `rooms.removeIf(r -> r.name().equals("whatever"));`.

Comment: MyRoom.removeRoom() works only for rooms with name "211". Better make the room-name a parameter of removeRoom().

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Are you getting an error message? Is the output not what you expect? Please edit your question and add this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your interface IRoom like this :

```
public void removeRoom(String name);
public int countRoomBySize(int size);
```

In the MyRoom class change removeRoom method like this :

```
@Override
public void removeRoom(String name){
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.size(); i++) {
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(rooms.get(i).getName())){
            rooms.removeIf(r -> r.getName().equals(name));
            System.out.println("Removed !");
        }
    }
}
```

And the countRoomBySize method like this :

```
@Override
public int countRoomBySize( int size){
     int s,i,n;
 n = rooms.size();
 s = 0;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
   if(rooms.get(i).getSize() > size) 
       s++;  
 }
 return(s); 
}
```

Best of luck !

Answer (score 0):

Nice that you are starting to learn java.

The simplest solution here is to put your room in an Hashmap and store the room number as key;

```
public class MyMain { 
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hashmap<String,Room> rooms = new Hashmap();
    rooms.add("211",new Room("HB201L",35);
    rooms.add("HB401R",new Room("HB401R",45);

    rooms.remove("211");
    int size = rooms.size();
    int smallRooms = calculateSmallRooms(rooms.values(),30);
    }


    private int calculateSmallRooms(Collection<Room> rooms, int minimalSize) {
    int smallRooms = 0;
    for(Room room: rooms) {
        if (room.size < minimalSize) {
          smallRooms++;
        }
    return smallRooms;
    }
```

Comment: Thank so much, I will learn HashMap but I'm trying to use ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

removeRoom can be shortened to: rooms.remove(rooms.indexOf("211")) or perhaps even rooms.remove("211");